# How to put table of UI5 smarttable inside of a scrollbar?

Tags: sapui5

I have a smarttable with custom toolbar and a table inside.

Now I want to put just the table and not the whole smarttable inside of a scroll container. But if I do that then data is not bound to the inner table anymore.

```
 <smartTable:SmartTable id="_0" entitySet="ProjectOrganisationHeadSet" tableBindingPath="/ProjectOrganisationHeadSet"
tableType="ResponsiveTable" smartFilterId="prorgrelWorklistFilterBarId" showFullScreenButton="true" useVariantManagement="false"
enableAutoBinding="true" ignoredFields="" beforeRebindTable="handleBeforeRebindTable" app:myStatus="EDIT"
initiallyVisibleFields="ProjectorgaId,Title,....">
<smartTable:customToolbar>
    <OverflowToolbar design="Transparent">
        <ToolbarSpacer/>
        <Button type="Transparent" press="onCreateBtnPress" icon="sap-icon://add"/>
    </OverflowToolbar>
</smartTable:customToolbar>
<ScrollContainer id="__scrollContainer0" horizontal="true" vertical="true">
    <Table id="table0" mode="None" busyIndicatorDelay="0">
        <items>
            <ColumnListItem type="Navigation" press="onPress">
                <cells>
                    <Text text="{path: 'ProjectorgaId', formatter: '.formatter.intNumber'}"/>
                </cells>
            </ColumnListItem>
        </items>
    </Table>
</ScrollContainer>
```

While it must show 40 rows, it shows nothing. If I remove the scrollcontainer all rows will be shown.

[image]

Comment: Hi Mahdi, did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi. Yes I found an alternative solution. https://blogs.sap.com/2018/05/03/fixed-header-for-ui5-smart-table/comment-page-1/#comment-422695

Comment: I don'T understand how your provided link helped to solve the problem? Did you get rid of the scroll container and achieved horizontal scrolling?

Comment: @felix9607 I wanted to keep the header of the table in a fixed position. The question was not about horizontal scroll it was about vertical scroll. And as I explained in my blog post I could find an alternative solution for that.